# C# when opening a .xls file in the web browser it opens an instance of excel

Tags: c#, excel

For my C# forms application I've seen multiple tutorials saying that it's possible to open an excel file within a web browser with the following code:

`this.webBrowser2.Navigate("filename", false);`
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati

However, when I try this, the web browser says "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" and Excel opens with the spreadsheet open in it.

Does anyone know how to stop this happening?

Cheers,

Tom

Edit:
I have solved this now - I will post the answer in seven hours (as users with under ten posts cannot answer their own question within the first eight hours of posting it)

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Just the normal webbrowser control in visual studio (I think that uses IE)

Comment: First of all I've never heard it was possible for a web browser to display Excel files... If so, I'd expect this to be a browser setting (open externally or internally).

Comment: so you are building a desktop app with integrated browser?

Comment: I'm having a look through the IE settings now Thorsten.
And yep, it's a Windows Forms app with a webbrowser control inside the form

Comment: I have solved this now - I will post the answer in seven hours (as users with under ten posts cannot answer their own question within the first eight hours of posting it)

Comment: This KB Entry (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059/en-us) shows how to configure the behaviour you do *not* want - maybe it gives you a clue on what to do in your case.

Comment: Thorsten, thanks. That's exactly what I did by editing the registry to reverse the solution that link gives. I'll post the answer to how I did it when I can.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved it!!

This problem is nothing to do with C# or Visual Studio, it's to do with how windows manages it's file types (I think).
This link tells you how to **stop** Excel files opening in Internet Explorer, so I just did the opposite to what they've said. (I did the registry edit method - method 2).
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways

To solve this problem:
Go to  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Classes**  and change the BrowserFlags data number to 1 for the following keys:

Excel.Sheet.8

Excel.Sheet.12

Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12

Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12

Then you're done.
This has worked for .xls files and .xlsx files and their related macro files for me. 
Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Cheers,

Tom

Comment: For those who can't modify the registry, here is an alternative solution http://alemiralles.blogspot.com.ar/2016/10/how-to-show-excel-files-inside-net.html